# Combine left join with commas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I've got this SQL code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM A a1, AP ap1, P p1, M m1 
LEFT JOIN F f1 ON f1.id_f = p1.f1
LEFT JOIN C c1 ON p1.c_id = c1.c_id
LEFT JOIN S s1 on p1.saison_id = s1.s_id
WHERE a1.a_type NOT IN (1) 
AND a1.type_c IN (1,2) 
AND ap1.a_id = a1.achats_id
AND p1.p_id = ap1.products_id
AND p1.m_id = m1.m_id
ORDER BY a_id ASC
```

And I get this error :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'p1.f1' in 'on clause'
```

So I have no idea why doesn't it recognize p1.f1 on line 3. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not combine `LEFT JOIN` with commas.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why? And if I had no choice (for X or Y reason), how can I still do it with both?

Comment: ***DON'T***  Why on either would you want to mix two syntax???  Just use `INNER JOIN` instead of `,`...  Mixing syntax leads to hard to read ambiguous code; What's the order of precedence in `a, b LEFT JOIN c, d`?  If you really must use `,`, then learn to use sub-queries and/or `(+)` notation for turning `,` in to an outer join *(but be warned that even then some logic can't be accurately expressed, that's why in 1992 the `JOIN` syntax was ratified; it clearer, and it actually works...)*.

Comment: Why would you have "no choice"? Just use  a proper join and everything is fine. You should never mix implicit and explicit joins - the error you have is just one reason for that. And the only choice you have to fix that is to use proper joins

Comment: Explicit `join` chains are evaluated before comma separated items, that's why p1's columns can't be used in the ON clause.

Comment: Comma does a cross join but binds after explicit JOINs. Read the manual. If you want the cross joins in the order written then replace eacj comma by CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply use proper `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A a1 JOIN
     AP ap1
     ON ap1.a_id = a1.achats_id JOIN
     P p1
     ON p1.p_id = ap1.products_id JOIN
     M m1 
     ON p1.m_id = m1.m_id LEFT JOIN
     F f1
     ON f1.id_f = p1.f1 LEFT JOIN
     C c1
     ON p1.c_id = c1.c_id LEFT JOIN
     S s1 
     ON p1.saison_id = s1.s_id
WHERE a1.a_type NOT IN (1) AND a1.type_c IN (1, 2) 
ORDER BY a1.a_id ASC;
```

Voila!  Problem solved.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` mean precisely the same thing in MySQL.

Comment: @Fobujasa . . . `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are synonyms in almost any database.